# Having problem using clang in WSL linking to vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I successfully installed clang in WSL(Ubuntu22.04), and it worked perfectly (I can compile and build my program), but when I linked it to vscode, intellisense worked but I can't compile my code.

When I first set it up I used `code .` to configure vscode in WSL as shown in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl

Although this article is using gcc but I thought clang would be the same.

When running it, vscode asked me to choose a debug configuration, but in the dropdown, it only had gbd, though I haven't installed gcc related build chain.

After selecting gdb, vscode generated an error message 'launch: program 'enter program name, for example /home/rubin/Program - Copy/a.out'
does not exist'

I suspect there's something wrong in launch.json but I don't know how to make it work, my current configuration is just

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": []
```

I don't know how to add clang into it as the template vscode provides only contains gdb/gcc.

Please help I am really desperate(；′⌒`)

Comment: It seems your `launch.json` file isn't configured correctly.

Comment: And please [***don't*** post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)! Copy-paste any and all text *as text* into your questions. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hi I re-edit my post, I hope this is better. I am not really sure how to configure launch.json regarding in order to use clang, so  I am a bit confused right now hmm

Comment: You have a link to the VSCode in WSL documentation, which explains all you should need to know about the `c_cpp_properties.json`, `tasks.json` and `launch.json` files. Including examples and how to create these files from within VSCode. Did you follow those instructions?  Using GCC or Clang *is* the same, but you still need to have a good configuration. Please read all of the documentation.